# Fancybox Iframe not in the centre of the page

Tags: php, iframe, fancybox

I am using fancybox iframe to show content however everytime when I scroll page the page ,the Iframe is not in the centre of the page. I want to Iframe will always be in centre of the page when scrolling. I am using this script.

```
$("#various2").fancybox({
  width: 520,
  height: 550,
  autoScale: false,
  transitionIn: 'none',
  transitionOut: 'none',
  type: 'iframe',
  scrolling: 'no',
  centerOnScroll: 'true',
  autoCenter: 'true'
});
```

Can anyone help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Some CSS rules override the fancybox ones?

Comment: "How-to" depends on what version of fancybox you are using because in your script you are including API options for v1.3.x and v2.x that are not compatible with each other. So the $64,000 question is : what fancybox version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I`m not sure, but by looking at your code, I can see that you have typed boolean values as strings -

```
$("#various2").fancybox({
  width: 520,
  height: 550,
  autoScale: false,
  transitionIn: 'none',
  transitionOut: 'none',
  type: 'iframe',
  scrolling: 'no',
  centerOnScroll: true, // and not 'true',
  autoCenter: true // and not 'true'
});
```